# Poll website that allows user entries and voting on those entries?

Tags: web-apps, polls

I am looking for a way to make a poll that allows people to add, say, movie suggestions.
Then everyone can also vote on the movie they want.
Preferably with some kind of ip check so people can't vote for the same option repeatedly.

The closest I found was poll.ly but that website seems to allow users to 'log into' other usernames and can therefore change peoples votes.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [PollUnit](https://pollunit.com).

You could create a [idea collection](https://pollunit.com/en/collect-ideas-and-feedback) with simple upvote or use the [voting](https://pollunit.com/en/voting) feature with various types of votes (star rating, dot voting...).

There is also a ip check, but keep in mind that people in companies or universities often share the same ip address! Another way would be to require an account or even more secure to require an invitation. You can limit participants in the advanced step in the wizard.

PollUnit is free for teams with up to 40 members.

Disclosure: I am one of the developers